# Communication between two AAD apps: error AADSTS65001

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-identity-platform

I am getting the error : “AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID ….

We have 2 app registrations on azure, lets say app A and app B. I trying to get some data from A to B.

In azure portal I already configured permission so the B app can have access to app A, and it's status is granted.

I'm using msal-angular library to authenticate the user and achieve that. Here is my configuration:

```
export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=[ ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']], ['endpoint of app A',['scope from the app A']] ];

MsalModule.forRoot({
        clientID: 'ClientId Of App B',
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/",
        validateAuthority: true,
        redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        cacheLocation : "localStorage",
        storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE, // set to true for IE 11
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
        navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
        popUp: !isIE,
        consentScopes: [ "user.read", "openid", "profile", "scope from the app A"],
        unprotectedResources: ["https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/"],
        protectedResourceMap: protectedResourceMap,
        logger: loggerCallback,
        correlationId: '1234',
        piiLoggingEnabled: true
      }
    )
```

So the first thing is to login in the app B, authentication is successful and the token is received and stored in the local storage. The second thing is making a http request to app A to get some data. When the http is called the error pops up.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue personally (but with a .Net Web app). You use the 'common' endpoint, so I guess it is a multi-tenant app registration.
I was unable to make my app work until I used the version 2 endpoint authority, i.e. add "/v2.0" to the authority field: